# Copy from chart to clipboard is too large is size

Tags: c#, clipboard, mschart

I am using the following code to copy from ms chart image to clipboard. But the image copied is in clip board is too large. Each of them becomes 3 MB. Is there any way to image compress the bitmap object? Not file compress but image compress like jpeg compress

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
    Clipboard.SetImage(bm);
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that it is "too large"?  Is this causing an error?

Comment: Yes, there are a few libraries: https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=compress%20bitmap%20c%23

Comment: try this msdn thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e755b7b-c0f3-46e3-b4cd-5881bf654d7f/c-convert-bitmap-to-bytes-or-high-compress

Comment: There is no error. But it is very inconvenient for engineers to send over several 3MB plots. I need to copy a low quality around 500 kb image to clipboard.

Comment: If this is for production code, you may want to think about what would happen if the user already has something on the clipboard that they wouldn't be too happy with your program trampling over...

Comment: I pasted in word document then copied again and the size of the image reduced quite a bit.
This is a commercial product. I will code a pop up informing users that existing clipboard will be replaced by the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the image to clipboard with `png` format which is a loss-less compressed image format. They can reach large file size depending on the image data saved.

In your code change the image format to `jpeg` as below to reduce the image size.

```
chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: I have tried Jpeg as well but does not compress. There compression modes for Jpeg. I need a code that does that compression

Comment: @YousufHossain - the compression depends on your image... depending on the image data you might not see much difference between compressed and uncompressed data...